# Javascript replace regex not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

In the code below I expected the string '/?_escaped_fragment_=/faq' to be converted to '/seo/faq'.

Instead of this, I am getting '/?/seo/faq'. What is wrong with the code?

```
var url = '/?_escaped_fragment_=/';
var rule = new RegExp('\/?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)');

alert(url.replace(rule,'/seo/$1')); // this shows up '/?/seo//'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLfuuw1p/5/

Comment: `?` has special meaning in regular expressions. Escape it, and use a regex literal instead of the `RegExp` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the `?` because it signifies that the previous character or group is optional.

Refer to this [Explanation on RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iA1yG3/1):

> `\/?` matches the character `/` literally
>
> Quantifier: `?` Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

This is the RegEx you need:

```
var rule = new RegExp('/\\?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)');
```

Note: in a `RegExp` constructor, escaping works with `\\`, not with `\`, because the double backslash is parsed as a single backslash in the string that you pass to the constructor and only then the regular expression even has *that* single backslash. If you only write one backslash, that one is consumed upon parsing it as a string, resulting in *no* backslashes for the regular expression.

Also, a `/` doesn’t need to be escaped in the string form, as this is automatically handled.

If it’s going to be static anyway, you can simply use a RegEx literal:

```
var rule = /\/\?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)/;
```

Comment: Why not just write a literal regexp so you don't have to worry about the double escaping? Also, **if** you're going to be passing a string to a regexp constructor there is no need to escape the forward slash.

Comment: Why double backslash?

Comment: @torazaburo `new RegExp` is useful if the regular expression is dynamic. I’m not sure about the OP’s full intentions.

Comment: @torazaburo You’re right about the forward slash, I’ve edited my post.

Comment: @wildbyte The double backslash is parsed as a single backslash in a string and only then the regular expression can parse _that_ single backslash. If you only write one backslash, one is consumed to convert it as a string, resulting in _no_ backslashes for the regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

`?` matches 0 or 1 of the preceding selector. You need to escape the `?` with a backslash for the regex, and then escape the backslash for the string:

```
var rule = new RegExp('\/\\?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)');
```

These double escaping problems are a product of using regular expression syntax within a string literal. Might as well save a few characters and use a regex literal:

```
var rule = /\/\?_escaped_fragment_=(.*)/;
```

Comment: Why not just write a literal regexp?

Comment: @torazaburo, give me a minute, I'm getting there.